# mysql 8 (innodb) foreign key constraints on newly created indexes

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

Suppose I have a table `items`
with columns `id (PRIMARY), name(VARCHAR), section_id (BIGINT), updated_at (DATETIME)`,

and a table `sections` with `id (PRIMARY)`.

Naturally, `items.section_id` is a foreign key that refers to `sections.id`.

Suppose there is an index on `items` of the columns `(section_id, name)`. I believe that if you tried to drop this index, you would get an error that it is `needed in a foreign key constraint`. I can accept this.

Now, I want to create a new index, like `create index ix_section_id_id_updated_at on items (section_id, id, updated_at)`. MySQL lets me do this, but if I go to drop this table, I get that same error: it fails, because it is `needed in a foreign key constraint`.

Why should this be? It already has one index that can be used for this foreign key check. Further, the error does NOT go away with `set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`.  Is there a way to force MySQL to not associate the new index with the foreign key, so that it is quick to drop? This is necessary because I will be running the migration on a production server with temporary downtime, and need to be able to quickly revert the migration in case of anything going wrong afterwards.

Comment: so have "naturally" a foreign key and are wondering why mysql claims that one exists?

Comment: no, wondering why the foreign key is being applied to the new index, as well. can one never drop an index that has a foreign key first, even if there's another index that allows the lookup?

Comment: no when you told you deleted the index, that not means that you have dropped the foreign key restraint, it still exists, why you can chekc by querying the information table

Comment: so if you create an index that references a foreign key, you can never delete it?

Comment: As you noticed, you first must drop the constraint.

Comment: Please provide that actual SQL being used and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I worry that some detail was lost in the translation to English.

Comment: @nbk dropping the constraint does not work.

Comment: @RickJames English is my native language, but by this time someone else understood what I was asking well enough to answer the question.

Comment: @gmoss - (Sorry, I should have said "translation from SQL to English".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue if I don't create an index on section_id and allow mysql to do so on the creation of a foreign key(as described in the manual). Adding a new index drops the auto generated key and if you then drop the new index an error is generated because of the requirement to have a key , and mysql does not auto generate one on a drop..  . If you manually generate a key on section_id this problem does not happen..and the newly created compound index drops successfully.

```
drop table if exists items;
drop table if exists sections;

create table items(id int PRIMARY key, name varchar(3), section_id BIGINT, updated_at DATETIME);

create table sections(id bigint primary key);

alter table items
    add foreign key fk1(section_id) references sections(id);
    
show create table items;

CREATE TABLE `items` (  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`name` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,  
`section_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
KEY `fk1` (`section_id`),  
CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

alter table items
    add key key1(section_id, name);

show create table items;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `key1` (`section_id`,`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and with manually generated key

```
drop table if exists items;
drop table if exists sections;

create table items(id int PRIMARY key, name varchar(3), section_id BIGINT, updated_at DATETIME);

create table sections(id bigint primary key);


alter table items
    add key sid(section_id);
alter table items
    add foreign key fk1(section_id) references sections(id);
    
show create table items;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sid` (`section_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

alter table items
    add key key1(section_id, name);

show create table items;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sid` (`section_id`),
  KEY `key1` (`section_id`,`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thank you!

I was able to figure out that MySQL actually is implicitly creating this index on `section_id`, and then implicitly deleting it when I manually created my new index. So I will be able to make the foreign key index explicit and therefore persistent.